# Arduino Uno: While-loop fails to "restart" using Button to reset Timer when second-pressing?

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

**What the code does:**

1. The code starts off by showing a short "blinking animation", where segments A-F turns on and off one at a time.
2. The "blinking animation" lasts between 3-10 seconds, upon which a timer starts.
3. The timer counts from 0-99 seconds displayed by Digit 1 & 2. While Digit 3 & 4 shows 10th and 100th, respectively, of a second.
4. By using the connected button, you can stop the timer by pressing it. Timer stops and shows the time.
5. By pressing down the button a second time it's supposed to restart the timer and send us back to Step 1.

> 

**My problem:** when I get to STEP 5 in the code, it won't restart. The problem is linked to the while-loop in the main function caused by, as far as I can see, the second while-loop in the function "stopTimer". Can't make it to exit the loop. At least that's what I've understood from all the numerous unsuccessful tries! Tried adding code with if-statements inside the "stopDisplay" function as well, including break; or return; etc.

> 

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BUTTONPRESSED PINC & 1 << PC0

    /*
    - PORT = D
    Segment-A   Pin 1   PD1     0B00000010
    Segment-B   Pin 2   PD2     0B00000100
    Segment-C   Pin 3   PD3     0B00001000
    Segment-D   Pin 4   PD4     0B00010000
    Segment-E   Pin 5   PD5     0B00100000
    Segment-F   Pin 6   PD6     0B01000000
    Segment-G   Pin 7   PD7     0B10000000

    - PORT = B
    Digit 1     Pin 10  PB2     0B00000100
    Digit 2     Pin 11  PB3     0B00001000
    Digit 3     Pin 12  PB4     0B00010000
    Digit 4     Pin 13  PB5     0B00100000

    - PORT = C
    Button      Pin A0  PC0     0B00000001
    */

//Number: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  in a array.
int segmentNumberArray[10] = {0B01111110, 0B00001100, 0B010110110, 0B10011110, 0B011001100, 0B11011010, 0B11111010, 0B00001110, 0B11111110, 0B11011110};

//Digit: 1, 2, 3, 4   in a array
int digitArrayOff[4] = {0B00000100, 0B00001000, 0B00010000, 0B00100000};
int digitArrayOn[4] = {0B11111011, 0B11110111, 0B11101111, 0B11011111};

//Blinking animation: segment-E, segment-D, segment-C, segment-G, segment-F, segment-A, segment-B, segment-G
int blinkingArray[8] = {0B00100000, 0B00010000, 0B00001000, 0B10000000, 0B01000000, 0B00000010, 0B00000100, 0B10000000};

long number = 0;
int recentTime;
int digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4;
int stopButton;

void startTimer();
void stopTimer();
void choseDigit(int x);
void showNumberOnDisplay(int x);
void blinkingAnimation();

int main()
{

  DDRC = 0;
  DDRD = 255;
  DDRB = 0B00111100; //DDRB = 28;

  srand(time(NULL));

  while (1)
  {
    if (number == 0)
    {
      int randomWaitTime = rand() % 10 + 3; //Calls random number between 3-10
      for (int i = 0; i < randomWaitTime; i++)
      {
        blinkingAnimation();
      }
    }
    startTimer();

    if (BUTTONPRESSED)
    {
      stopButton = 0;
      stopTimer();
    }
    
    if (BUTTONPRESSED)
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}

void startTimer()
{
  PORTD = 0B00000000;                   //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(1);                        //Turn Display 1 on
  showNumberOnDisplay((number / 1000)); //Get value of thousand
  _delay_ms(1);                         //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;                         //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(2);                              //Turn Display 2 on
  showNumberOnDisplay((number % 1000) / 100); //Get value of hundred
  _delay_ms(1);                               //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;                     //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(3);                          //Turn Display 3 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(number % 100 / 10); //Get value of ten
  _delay_ms(1);                           //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;               //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(4);                    //Turn Display 3 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(number % 10); //Get value of single digit
  _delay_ms(1);                     //Delay 1 ms

  number++;
  if (number == 9999) // Reset number count to 1;
  {
    number = 1;
  }
}

void stopTimer()
{
  recentTime = number;
  digit1 = recentTime / 1000;
  digit2 = (recentTime % 1000) / 100;
  digit3 = recentTime % 100 / 10;
  digit4 = recentTime % 10;

  while (stopButton == 0)
  {
    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(1);               //Turn Display 1 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit1); //Get value of thousand
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(2);               //Turn Display 2 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit2); //Get value of hundred
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(3);               //Turn Display 3 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit3); //Get value of ten
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(4);               //Turn Display 3 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit4); //Get value of single digit
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms
  }
}

void choseDigit(int x)
{
  PORTB = 0B11111111;
  switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[0]; //Display 1 on
    break;

  case 2:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[1]; //Display 2 on
    break;

  case 3:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[2]; //Display 3 on
    break;

  case 4:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[3]; //Display 4 on
    break;
  }
}

void showNumberOnDisplay(int x)
{
  switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[1];
    break;

  case 2:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[2];
    break;

  case 3:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[3];
    break;

  case 4:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[4];
    break;

  case 5:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[5];
    break;

  case 6:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[6];
    break;

  case 7:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[7];
    break;

  case 8:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[8];
    break;

  case 9:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[9];
    break;

  default:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[0];
    break;
  }
}

void blinkingAnimation()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    PORTD = blinkingArray[i];
    _delay_ms(125);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is finally a solution to my problem above. Thought I post it in case anyone else runs into a similar problem:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define BUTTONPRESSED PINC &(1 << PC0)

/*
    - PORT = D
    Segment-A   Pin 1   PD1     0B00000010
    Segment-B   Pin 2   PD2     0B00000100
    Segment-C   Pin 3   PD3     0B00001000
    Segment-D   Pin 4   PD4     0B00010000
    Segment-E   Pin 5   PD5     0B00100000
    Segment-F   Pin 6   PD6     0B01000000
    Segment-G   Pin 7   PD7     0B10000000

    - PORT = B
    Digit 1     Pin 10  PB2     0B00000100
    Digit 2     Pin 11  PB3     0B00001000
    Digit 3     Pin 12  PB4     0B00010000
    Digit 4     Pin 13  PB5     0B00100000

    - PORT = C
    Button      Pin A0  PC0     0B00000001
    */

//Number: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9  in a array
int segmentNumberArray[10] = {0B01111110, 0B00001100, 0B010110110, 0B10011110, 0B011001100, 0B11011010, 0B11111010, 0B00001110, 0B11111110, 0B11011110};

//Digit: 1, 2, 3, 4   in a array
int digitArrayOff[4] = {0B00000100, 0B00001000, 0B00010000, 0B00100000};
int digitArrayOn[4] = {0B11111011, 0B11110111, 0B11101111, 0B11011111};

//Blinking animation: segment-E, segment-D, segment-C, segment-G, segment-F, segment-A, segment-B, segment-G
int blinkingArray[8] = {0B00100000, 0B00010000, 0B00001000, 0B10000000, 0B01000000, 0B00000010, 0B00000100, 0B10000000};

long number = 0;
int recentTime;
int digit1, digit2, digit3, digit4;
int isCounting = 0;
int isButtonDown = 0;

void startTimer();
void stopTimer();
void choseDigit(int x);
void showNumberOnDisplay(int x);
void blinkingAnimation();

int main()
{

  DDRC = 0; // För knappen -->> alt. DDRC&= ~(1 << PC0);
  DDRD = 255;
  DDRB = 0B00111100; //DDRB = 28; -->> detta är för Displayerna

  srand(time(NULL));
  blinkingAnimation();

  while (1)
  {
    if (isCounting == 1)
    {
      startTimer();
    }

    if (BUTTONPRESSED)
    {
      if (isButtonDown == 0)  //Button has not been pressed before
      {
        isButtonDown = 1;
        if (isCounting == 0)
        {
          
          blinkingAnimation();
        }
        else
        {
        isCounting = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      isButtonDown = 0;  //Button has been released
    }

    stopTimer();
  }

  return 0;
}

void startTimer()
{
  PORTD = 0B00000000;                   //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(1);                        //Turn Display 1 on
  showNumberOnDisplay((number / 1000)); //Get value of thousand
  _delay_ms(2.3);                       //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;                         //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(2);                              //Turn Display 2 on
  showNumberOnDisplay((number % 1000) / 100); //Get value of hundred
  _delay_ms(2.3);                             //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;                     //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(3);                          //Turn Display 3 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(number % 100 / 10); //Get value of ten
  _delay_ms(2.3);                         //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;               //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(4);                    //Turn Display 4 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(number % 10); //Get value of single digit
  _delay_ms(2.3);                   //Delay 1 ms

  number++;
  if (number > 5999) // Reset number count to 1;
  {
    number = 1;
  }
}

void stopTimer()
{
  recentTime = number;
  digit1 = recentTime / 1000;
  digit2 = (recentTime % 1000) / 100;
  digit3 = recentTime % 100 / 10;
  digit4 = recentTime % 10;

    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(1);               //Turn Display 1 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit1); //Get value of thousand
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(2);               //Turn Display 2 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit2); //Get value of hundred
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(3);               //Turn Display 3 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit3); //Get value of ten
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

    PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
    choseDigit(4);               //Turn Display 3 on
    showNumberOnDisplay(digit4); //Get value of single digit
    _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms
}

void choseDigit(int x)
{
  PORTB = 0B11111111;
  switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[0]; //Display 1 on
    break;

  case 2:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[1]; //Display 2 on
    break;

  case 3:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[2]; //Display 3 on
    break;

  case 4:
    PORTB = digitArrayOn[3]; //Display 4 on
    break;
  }
}

void showNumberOnDisplay(int x)
{
  switch (x)
  {
  case 1:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[1];
    break;

  case 2:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[2];
    break;

  case 3:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[3];
    break;

  case 4:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[4];
    break;

  case 5:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[5];
    break;

  case 6:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[6];
    break;

  case 7:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[7];
    break;

  case 8:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[8];
    break;

  case 9:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[9];
    break;

  default:
    PORTD = segmentNumberArray[0];
    break;
  }
}

void blinkingAnimation()
{
  PORTB = digitArrayOn[4];
  //Random wait time:
  int randomWaitTime = rand() % 10 + 3; //Calls random number between 3-10 seconds

  for (int i = 0; i < randomWaitTime; i++)
  {
    //Blink animation:
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      PORTD = blinkingArray[i];
      _delay_ms(125);
    }
  }
  number = 0;
  isCounting = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the value of variable **stopButton** still 0, resulting stopButton == 0 return true.
But i think it better to use variable to represent the state.

```
#define STATE_COUNT 1
#define STATE_STOP 2
int currentState = 1;
while(1){
  if(currentState == STATE_COUNT && BUTTONPRESSED){
     //do something

     currentState = STATE_STOP;
  }
  if(currentState == STATE_STOP && BUTTONPRESSED){
     //do something

     currentState = STATE_COUNT;
  }
}
```

> edited

so, my idea is to use STATE to define what code to run. so you can eliminate second while loop.

```
while (1) {
  if(currentState == STATE_BLINK){
    blink(); //run code 1 time and change state
    currentState = STATE_COUNT;
  }
  if(currentState == STATE_COUNT){
    startTimer(); 
  }
  if(currentState == STATE_STOP){
    stopTimer(); // while loop inside is removed
  }


  if (BUTTONPRESSED) {
    //change state here
  }
}

void stopTimer() {
  recentTime = number;
  digit1 = recentTime / 1000;
  digit2 = (recentTime % 1000) / 100;
  digit3 = recentTime % 100 / 10;
  digit4 = recentTime % 10;

  PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(1);               //Turn Display 1 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(digit1); //Get value of thousand
  _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(2);               //Turn Display 2 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(digit2); //Get value of hundred
  _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(3);               //Turn Display 3 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(digit3); //Get value of ten
  _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms

  PORTD = 0B00000000;          //Turn ALL segments off
  choseDigit(4);               //Turn Display 3 on
  showNumberOnDisplay(digit4); //Get value of single digit
  _delay_ms(1);                //Delay 1 ms 
}

void blink(){
 if (number == 0) {
  int randomWaitTime = rand() % 10 + 3; //Calls random number between 3-10
  for (int i = 0; i < randomWaitTime; i++) {
    blinkingAnimation();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: I even tried to add `stopButton = 1` with an if-statement to stop the while-loop with and without break or return to force it to exit somehow. However, that didn't help at all, just caused other unwated behaviour. Apology for my lack of knowledge as I'm new to C. I've seen something similar like this, but I just don't know to implement it. I tried this but it didn't work out = in the `if(currentState == STATE_COUNT && BUTTONPRESSED)` statement I included: stopButton = 0, stopTime();, while in the second one I didn't know what to include and just added  `break;`. Confused, sorry mate.

Comment: Hermenstian IW - I tried it in all kinds of ways and combination. Can't get it to work :/. It just breaks the code and everything goes blank. Not sure how to implement the above. Appreciate if you could elaborate it more.

Comment: Sorry if i cant explain clearly, i edited my answer.

Comment: I tried your example above still won't work....this is sooo frustrating! I'm wondering, can it be the button where the problem is? But I can't see anything wrong there and the button should be fine using Bit-operators to activate it and shouldn't need any kind of reset? I edited your answer with a new block so you can see what I did when trying out your suggested code. See if there's anything weird going on there?